# I want to become a salesforce developer

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow

I did my Masters in computer science but have no knowledge of any language properly, i want to become a salesforce developer, is it easy because i am network engineer but now i want to start my carrier with salesforce developer...please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to register yourself on Salesforce Trailhead and spend sometime on developer modules.

URL: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to learn Salesforce.

Use trailhead to learn salesforce : [Salesforce Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead)

Register for upcoming free webinars for quick introduction on Apex, VF and so on. [Webinars](https://developer.salesforce.com/calendar)

Visit Developer blogs to know about Salesforce. [Blogs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/?language=en)

Answer (score 0):

Trail heads can be your basic step. Then follow some structured courses specifically based on certification.

Also note that you need to be good in Admin and Dev to become successful in salesforce. Also certification is very crucial and need to take it for success in salesforce.

I recommend you to start with Administrator Certification and then followed by Platform App builder and then Developer certification. Because the initial two certification will give you the basics and then follow your interest by taking the advance certification like Developer mode.

I recommend below sites for your reference

1. Trail heads - A must for the newbies and starters
2. Certifiedondemand - paid, but worth for that amount
3. Udacity - training courses free & paid
4. Udemy - similar to Udacity
5. Communities - you can google it to get access to various related communities